# Can not open new window in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a second window in my website for a popunder as assigned by my hierarchy. So I made this code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
var popunderUrl = 'https://www.google.com';
window.open(window.location.href);
window.location.href = popunderUrl;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there is no extra code that can interfere with the JavaScript.

It works as intended on IE and Edge, but not in FireFox and Chrome. Do these browsers block this behaviour by default?

Comment: Yes, they do. The user can choose to allow popups per site.

Comment: I tried this code on chrome on this page and it worked fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do these browsers block this behaviour by default?

Yes. Opening new windows on page load is routinely abused, so many browsers disallow it. If your code didn't navigate away from the page, you might see a notification from the browser saying that Page XYZ wanted to open a popup, which the user could then allow if they wanted. But because you navigate away, the user doesn't have a chance to do that.

You'll have to tell the people telling you to do this that browsers actively try to defeat it, and even if you find a way to make it work today, that's no guarantee that it'll work tomorrow. (Whereas if other people are anything like me, doing it is a great way to guarantee that people never visit your site again. ;-) )

Comment: Thanks, good enough for me. I personally don’t agree with this user story either, so I’ll try to persuade my product owners that this is not the way to go.